# Cambiar formato microtime en PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

tengo el sigueitne codigo:

```
$tiempo_inicialp = microtime(true); 
$test=TestDomain($dominio, $cpeticiones, $pconcurrentes);

//finalizamos el tiempo de la prueba:
$tiempo_finalp = microtime(true);
$tiempop = $tiempo_finalp - $tiempo_inicialp;
```

y recibo tiempos como estos:
2.6941299438477E-5
3.2901763916016E-5

esto son segundos, me gustaría cambiar el formato a por ejemplo
2.69
3.29

he probado varias cosas pero no me han funcionado

alguna sugerencia?
Gracias

Comment: ¿que cosas has probado?

Comment: he probado con cosas como esta:
  echo "el timepo de esta prueba es de: ". $tiempop("5.2");
pero no me han dado resultado

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver tu problema solo debes utilizar la función `number_format()`.

Quedaría mas o menos de la siguiente manera:

```
$tiempo_inicialp = microtime(true); 

$tiempo_inicialp = (float) number_format($tiempo_inicialp, 2);
```

Y te devolvería el numero con dos decimales, si quieres mas decimales solo debes cambiar el número 2 por el numero de decimales que necesites.

[Mas información en la documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php).